# Calling my R, instead of android.R

Tags: android

How can I access the R class from classes that were not inherited from Activity. So when I write R.something, I implicitly call android.R.something.

What is the explicit way of call R.something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just import the version of `R` that you want. If you need to access values in both classes, at least one of them will have to be fully qualified.

Note that inheriting from `Activity` has nothing to do with using you project's `R` values without an `import` statement. It's whether the code is in the application package as declared in the manifest.

Comment: to clarify:  at the top of you java file is `import Android.R;` so replace this with `import my.project.R`

Comment: Thanks, It was so simple. Didn't even notice it.

Answer (score 0):

If there are errors in your resources, you wont get a R in your gen directory. Check the console log output for extra information. Anything colored red tends to be really important :) other than that, qualify your package directly as already mentioned